# Script renaming on Synology NAS

Tags: linux, bash, synology

I have a Synology Nas that has a lot of files with invalid characters (the Nas does not grant permissions to users to access the file if such character exists in the name) such as `* . " / \ [ ] : ; | = ,` I have managed to get CLI on the box and was wondering if there is a way to change the file names on all shared folders or change the offending characters with `_`. The file tree structure is quite deep.

Comment: Those are not "invalid" characters. Though having a slash in a name which does not designate a directory separator will have to be exposed e.g. to Unix clients as something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command here:

```
find / -name "*" -exec ~/bin/some_script_that_will_rename_files.sh {} \;
```

and you need a script that will rename files as you like. E.g. it might replace all characters with something else.

Question is, whether you have these weird characters only inside file names or whether they are in directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can run Perl on it with:

```
perl -v
```

If it runs, you can install, or see if the Perl `rename` scripts runs and it can very easily rename files. Example:

```
touch "Freddy :;|=, Frog"                         # create file with mad name

rename --dry-run 's/[:;|=,]/_/g' *Frog            # see what it would become
'Freddy :;|=, Frog' would be renamed to 'Freddy _____ Frog'
```

I have done some other examples - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306621/2836621).

---

If you can't use `rename`, then you can use something like this but please test it on some **COPIES** of a few files first and make a backup before running it.

Here I am just testing on GIF files, so I don't make a mess. Also, I don't actually do amything, I just output what I would do:

```
find . -iname "*gif" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); echo "mv {} $new"' \;
```

If that looks correct, you would need to do this actual command:

```
find . -iname "*gif" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
```

which is slightly different because there is no `echo` and I need to double-quote parameters to `mv`.

Comment: Unfortunately perl rename is not present on the system
The `mv` command is present. Is there a way to combine the `find` and `mv` command to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Mark Setchell and mko for their help.
I ended up with the following commands

```
find . -iname "*:*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*<*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*>*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*|*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*?*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*[*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*]*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
find . -iname "*\*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(tr ";:|" "___" <<< "{}"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
```

Comment: Where you're injecting the filenames into Bash code, filenames that contain double quotes may cause problems. The safe way is to pass them as arguments. As well, use `--` to guard `mv` against filenames that start with hyphens, which would be taken as options. So: `find ... -exec bash -c 'new=$(... <<< "$1"); mv -- "$1" "$new"' bash {} \;` (the extra `bash` is for `$0`, which is unused).

Comment: Also you could reduce duplication using logical OR and grouping: `find . \( -name "*:*" -o -name "*<*" -o ... \) -exec ...` (`-name` and `-iname` are synonymous in this case).

Answer (score 0):

'brename' is a Go binary wich does the heavy lifting.
spent a lot of time trying to solve in bash (synology nas is busybox, ubuntu is dash nowadays) regexing.
https://github.com/shenwei356/brename

it has binaries for linux 64-bit(depending on age of your nas).

ssh into your nas, wget download binary, from link.  hack away.

./brename -d -R -p ":" -r " " /volume1/share_name
(remove -d  --dry-run)

longer answer:
(open a terminal of shell)
$ ssh admin@nas_ip_adress_or_dns_name [you can later $sudo su root with the admin password]
$ wget https://github.com/shenwei356/brename/releases/download/v2.7.0/brename_linux_amd64.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf brename (press tab to autocomplete)
then
$ ./brename -R -p ":" -r " " /volume1/share_name
add --dry-run to first see the effect without modification.  above line replaces all ":" with a space character.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to follow the guidelines for software recommendations provided [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/911683).

Answer (score 0):

Posting a variation on the above using `sed`:

```
   find . -iname "*:*" -exec bash -c 'new=$(sed 's/:/___/' <<< "{}"); echo "{}" "$new"' \;
```

> This is my preference only for readability and I'm only `echo`-ing above for safety. You'll want to use `mv` as others have noted.